# strdup causing memory leak

Tags: c

`strdup()` is causing memory leaks everytime it's used in `readLine()` (bc of its auto malloc) bc Im not freeing/deallocating the memory right.

I've tried to get the adress of the word and many other methods for hours now but with no progress.

I'm doing a calloc bc I'll be storing an undetermined #of words.

This has been hardcoded (only 3 words) as to show the working example. If I get a huge amount of words in the file, the memory leak will be too important.

***Text:***
`JOHN VELMA ZORRO`

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct link {
    char *word;
    struct link *next;
};

void readLine(FILE *file, char **words) {
   int i = 0;
   char ligne[80];
   while (fgets(ligne, 80, file)){
      char *word = strtok(ligne, " ,.-\n");
      while (word != NULL) {
         words[(i)++] = strdup(word);         //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<     
         word = strtok(NULL, " ,.-\n");
      }
   }
   fclose(file);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
   char **words = calloc(3, 30 * sizeof(char *) + 1);
   readLine(file, words);
   struct link *head = malloc(sizeof(struct link));
   struct link *ptrr = head;
   head->word = words[0];
   head->next = NULL;
   for (int i = 1; i < 4; ++i) {
      struct link *ptr, *temp;
      if (words[i] != 0) {
         ptr = head;
         temp = malloc(sizeof(struct link));
         temp->word = words[i];
         temp->next = NULL;
         while (ptr->next != NULL)
            ptr = ptr->next;
         ptr->next = temp;
      }
   }
   int a = 0;
   while (ptrr != NULL) {
      printf("Noeud#%d ->%s\n", a, ptrr->word);
      ptrr = ptrr->next;
      a++;
   }

//////freeing **words 

 struct link *tmpp;
   while (head != NULL) {
      tmpp = head;
      head = head->next;
      free(tmpp);
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
      free(words[i]);
   }
   free(words);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you adding 1 in the `calloc()` call?

Comment: When you use `calloc()` the first argument is the number of array elements, the second argument is just the `sizeof` for a single array element. So if you want room for 30 strings pointers, it should be `calloc(30, sizeof(char*))`. `calloc()` does the multiplication itself, you don't have to do it when calling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no , strdup is not causing a memory leak, you are by not freeing the memory it allocates. I note that you dont free any of your memory (the calloc and mallocs you do explictly)

strdup is this

```
 char *strdup(const char*s){
       int len = strlen(s) + 1;
       char * res = malloc(len);
       if(res != NULL)
          strcpy(res, s);
       return res
 }
```

there is no magic, its just a nice utility function that encapsulates a common set of operations.

You have to free the memory it returns, just like all the other allocations

Comment: I know whats returning, but when I try to free words[i] and words there seems to some memoring thats not being deallocated. I added it into my code in the example. I guess Im deallocating it wrong, but Im out of ideas.

Comment: did you run it under valgrind?

Comment: yes, thats how I know Im not deallocating/freeing correctly bc of strdup.

Comment: @LIsa so whats the question, valgrind reports not leaks, what makes you tink there are leaks => ==6851==   total heap usage: 10 allocs, 10 frees, 6,380 bytes allocated

Comment: @LIsa its reporting a leak in my complete code with a file with multiple words, coming out exactly of strdup. Im really puzzled now. Ill go debug more deeply I think. Thanks though!

Comment: @LIsa can you paste the whole file? or at least a bigger chunk

Comment: @LIsa ok it leaks with a bigger file , thats a clue for you

Answer (score 0):

THe reason you leak with a bigger file is this

You read the entire file into words (in readline). Note that you only reserve enough spaces for 30 words, so thats a potential error

```
   while (fgets(ligne, 80, file)) {
        char* word = strtok(ligne, " ,.-\n");
        while (word != NULL) {
            words[(i)++] = _strdup(word);           
            word = strtok(NULL, " ,.-\n");
        }
    }
```

so lets say there are 15 words you strdup 15 times

Then you build a list

```
for (int i = 1; i < 4; ++i) {  <<<=======
    struct link* ptr, * temp;
    if (words[i] != 0) {
        ptr = head;
        temp = malloc(sizeof(struct link));
        temp->word = words[i];
        temp->next = NULL;
        while (ptr->next != NULL)
            ptr = ptr->next;
        ptr->next = temp;
    }
}
```

but you only take the first 4 words.

Then when you free you only free those 4

```
struct link* tmpp;
while (head != NULL) {
    tmpp = head;
    head = head->next;
    free(tmpp);
}
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) { <<<<=============
    free(words[i]);
}
free(words);
```

the other 11 are leaked